# create calls before_save multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a before_save callback in my model which encrypts 2 fields before they're saved to the database.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_credentials, if: "!username.blank? && !password.blank?"

  def encrypt_credentials
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    self.username = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(username)
    self.password = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(password)
  end

  def decrypted_username
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    crypt.decrypt_and_verify(username)
  end

  def decrypted_password
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    crypt.decrypt_and_verify(password)
  end
end
```

The situation is very similar to [Devise models run before_save multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882423/devise-models-run-before-save-multiple-times). When I call Model.create!(...) - which includes the 2 fields that need to be encrypted, the before_save gets called twice, ending up in the fields being encrypted twice.

```
Account.create!(
{
  username: ENV['USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['PASSWORD']
})
```

Why is before_save called multiple times? I don't like the solution of the post linked above and I don't want to do new/build followed by save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was user error :( After calling account = Account.create!, I had other code which called save! back on the model: account.foo = bar; account.save!. This obviously called befor_save again and re-encrypted my fields. I ended up with something like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_username, if: :username_changed?
  before_save :encrypt_password, if: :password_changed?

  def encrypt_username
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    self.username = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(username)
  end

  def encrypt_password
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    self.password = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(password)
  end

  def decrypted_username
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    crypt.decrypt_and_verify(username)
  end

  def decrypted_password
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(ENV['KEY'])
    crypt.decrypt_and_verify(password)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 (could be a mistake in usage of callbacks):**

Short answer: use after_save instead of before_save

Long answer: [How to organize complex callbacks in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532911/how-to-organize-complex-callbacks-in-rails/11544635#11544635)

When you use the:

`account = Account.new`

`account.save`

You are firing the before_save hook each time.

**Option 2 (could be a bug):**

Maybe you're actually touching the record several times.

For example in:

```
def create
  @account = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]).accounts.create(account_params)

  if @account.save
    redirect_to customer_account_path(@account.customer.id, @account.id)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You are in fact touching it with create and save. In which case I suggest:

```
def create
  @account = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]).accounts.build(account_params)

  if @account.save
    redirect_to customer_account_path(@account.customer.id, @account.id)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Build doesn't try to save the record so you shouldn't have any more problems. Hope this helps! Have a great day!